# Chrome extension Content Scripting

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to know is there a way chrome extension can access background webpage url. example: I have search button in chrome extension and I am trying to execute URL in current window of web browser is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to get the currently active tab in the current or any other window.

Comment: but even if you get active tab info. my scenario is to have search box in my chrome extension and search for particular string in extension and the results should show in current browser window is it possible how?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can display a search box in the popup defined in the "browser_action" section of your extension's manifest. You can inject a content script which receives the search query from the extension and modifies the page displayed in the current window.